# I have these two errors in Android tourist app

Tags: android

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Have you read the link it provided to you? The first error should be solvable by reading and understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

Your app exceeded .dex file limitation. You need to remove some unused library, clean up your code or add multidex support.

If you want add multidex support, add this to your gradle file :

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

and this to your manifest :

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

More info here :
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Also u can use this library, so you can know how much method-references remains to limit.

https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin

Comment: "You need to remove some unused library," -- > especially google libraries where you can only include a part of the library instead of the whole services